# Not able to install perf in ubuntu 22.04 on raspberry pi 4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

Trying to install `perf` package. used below command to install it.

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-common
```

but when I run `perf`, it gave below output

```
WARNING: perf not found for kernel 5.11.0-1027

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-5.11.0-1027-raspi
    linux-cloud-tools-5.11.0-1027-raspi

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-raspi
    linux-cloud-tools-raspi
```

So tried installing `linux-tools-5.11.0-1027-raspi` but it gave below error

```
$ sudo apt install linux-tools-5.11.0-1027-raspi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.11.0-1027-raspi
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-tools-5.11.0-1027-raspi'
```

Comment: As far as i can tell, perf is ignored by Ubuntu